# Как снизить использование памяти QQuickWidget'а

Tags: qt5, qml

Не пойму, почему так много расходится память для отображения qml файла. Вот скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

C++

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QQuickWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QQuickWidget widget;
    widget.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("text.qml"));
    widget.setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    widget.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

text.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
Item
{
    width: 150
    height: 200

    Rectangle
    {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "#66ff99"
    }

}
```

Почему для отображения простого прямоугольника, нужно столько памяти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так же можно утсановить вот этот флаг, который снижает потребеление памяти в 5 раз.

```
QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::Software);
```

Беспонятие, что этот флаг значит, но работает он бесподобно.

Comment: "Беспонятие, что этот флаг значит, но работает он бесподобно." - убило)

Answer (score 3):

QML - наследник программного инструмента [QtScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtScript), который в свою очередь реализует полноценный JavaScript интерпритатор со своим Garbage Collector, глобальными объектами (например, [XMLHttpRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-xmlhttprequest-example.html), который доступен как в js, так и qml), а так же механизмами прототипного наследования. То, что суммарно программа потребляет так много памяти это норма в 2019 году...

Теоретически, можно обнулить какие-то части [глобального объекта](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeglobalobject.html) QML. В принципе, если вам не нужны HTTP запросы прямо с QML разметки. На практике - 100+ мегабайт это совершенно нормальное потребление памяти для приложения, которое взаимодействует с API целевой операционной системы через абстракцию.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("application.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

P.S. Если приложение использует только функциональность QML, возможно, применение класса QGuiApplication вместо QApplication поможет сэкономить память.

Comment: Ну, да... QGuiApplication экономит где-то 50-60 мегабайт. Просто не верится, чтоб так много памяти уходило.

Comment: Кстати, раз уж тема про память. Хочу спросить. Вот в VS показывается, что расходуется, допустим, 100 мб, а в диспетчере задач в два раза меньше. Кто врет и где правда?

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov тут тема такая: вокруг памяти, востребованной текущим процессом, туча памяти, которая необходима самой ОС. Это хорошо видно в том же C#, который для Windows является чуть ли не нативным языком программирования.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/dotnet/2018.3/t3_timeline.png

В dotmemory зелененьким - что жрет C#, остальное - НЁХ

Comment: Окей. То есть я могу смотреть на диспетчер задач, чтобы знать сколько в итоге будет кушать сам exe-шник?

Comment: @MichaelShcherbakov единовременное потребление памяти - не самая большая проблема. Некоторые сигналы выбрасывают указатели, если действие циклично и они не удаляются, память начинает течь. Смотреть надо и туда, и туда. И лучше - чаще.

Comment: Ну, это безусловно конечно) Спасибо за помощь!